# If using forceUpdate() is discouraged, how should components react to change events in the model?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use the following pattern in several components throughout my app. I notice that many people discourage using forceUpdate(), and some even call it a hack. So how should this be done without using it?

```
// user.js

export default class User extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(args) {
        super();
        this.id = args.id;
        this.isActivated = args.isActivated || false;
    }
    activate() {
        this.isActivated = true;
        this.emit('change');
    }
}

// UserView.jsx

export default class UserView extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.user.on('change', this.onUserUpdate);
    }
    onUserUpdate() {
        this.forceUpdate();
    }
    render (
        var user = this.props.user;
        return (
            <div>
                <span>User {user.isActivated ? 'is' : 'is not'} activated.</span>
                <button onClick={user.activate()}>Activate</button>
            </div>
        );
    );
}

// app.js

var user = new User({ id: 123 });
ReactDOM.render(<UserView user={user} />, container);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using MobX, a reactive paradigm that makes state observable and automatically upates observing components.

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx

Answer (score 6):

React will automatically render the component when either the props or state change.

If you have a model with changing properties then you should either keep it in the component's local state.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({
    user: this.props.user
  });
}
activator(user) {
  return () => {
    // mutate the user instance
    user.activate();
    // update the state to trigger render
    this.setState({ user });
  };
}
render (
  var user = this.state.user;
  return (
    <div>
      <span>User {user.isActivated ? 'is' : 'is not'} activated.</span>
      <button onClick={activator(user)}>Activate</button>
    </div>
  );
)
```

Even this is a bit hacky and storing unserializable data (prototype relationships, functions) in state isn't great. We're also mutating the object whilst it's in state (eek!).

An (arguably) more elegant way to solve this problem would be to use a simple object without any instance methods to represent users. Then write a set of pure operation functions that return new user objects reflecting the changes.

```
// user factory
function User(args) {
  return {
    id: args.id,
    isActivated: args.isActivated || false
  };
}

function activate(user) {
  // returns a new copy with the isActivated property set to true
  return Object.assign({}, user, { isActivated: true });

  // or with ES2016 object spread
  return { ...user, isActivated: true };
}
```

We can treat these user objects as immutable ([freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) them if you want). Then you can modify the activator code to be more functional.

```
activator(user) {
  return () => {
    this.setState({ user: activate(user) });
  }
}
```

Now when you click the activate button we update the state of the component with a new object and the old one is free to be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like the concept but it is not practical because components higher up or in different branches of the component tree will not hear about the changes. I could designate a root component as a controller that passes down functions as props such as onActivateUser. But I don't like the idea of passing down extra props through several levels just to reach a nested component, or updating the whole component tree just because a leaf component needs to update.

Comment: Furthermore, there are other things that can mutate the model outside of the view. For example, I am using the soundManager2 library which emits events as audio tracks play, which in turn mutate model properties such as playCount. It seems as though I am stuck with this event-driven pattern.

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit a lot from the Flux architecture. Move your state out of your components and into higher level stores that components can subscribe to. Then you can map your models directly to props, that will re-render the component when they change.

Comment: I have read about Flux and Redux, but it seemed too complicated, I didn't like all the constants and switch statements. But I know I should not be mutating models in the view, and it is better to pass down immutable objects. I am going to try to build a very simple flux-ish pattern by making data flow through a userActions.js and a userStore.js, and linking it all together with RxJS.

Comment: Honestly, Flux boilerplate might seem complicated, but once you only need to do it once and it will seem trivial from there onward. Flux doesn't care how you get the data from your store to the component, but RxJS is definitely a good solution, especially if you put your observables around immutable representations of your models.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that constants and switch statements are just the standard way to do Flux, but you don't have to use either. Dispatch an action of whatever shape/type you want, then implement your own handling strategy for it that uses an alternative to switch.